# CAPL Accessing integer signal with more than 52 bits

Tags: capl, canoe, canalyzer

The question is regarding CAPL signal access. Let's assume that in the code there is 64-bit unsigned integer signal from some PDU.

While trying to assign signal value to `sysvar` or `qword` variable like:

```
@sysvar::bar = $foo;
```

The warning shows up:

```
CAPL / .NET Accessing integer signal '[...]/foo' with more than 52 bits, possible loss of data!
```

In CANoe help regarding warning `2808` I've found that

```
In $ instructions only integer signals with up to 52 bits can be used without data loss, as values are saved and disclosed internally as doubles.
```

Have you any idea how may I assign 64-bit unsigned integer signal value without data loss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution in documentation:

> Due to the data type double, `.raw` does not return the exact values for
> signals longer than 52 bit. Please use for these signal lengths `.raw64`
> with the data type `int64`.
>
> ```
> int64 largeValue;
> largeValue = $Some64bitSignal.raw64;
> ```