# How to assign a CHAR Array to a SIGNAL (64 Bits) in CAPL script (CANOE)

Tags: capl, canoe

How do I assign a CHAR ARRAY (8 Bytes) into a SIGNAL (64 Bits) in CAPL script ?

Comment: How is the mapping between a char array and a 64 bit integer supposed to look like?

Answer (score 0):

Convert array to 64-bit variable minding the endianness.

Here's an example code:

```c
qword value;
value = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    value = value | (qword)array[i] << (8* (7 - i));
}
```

Due to the [fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260901/capl-accessing-integer-signal-with-more-than-52-bits/66261399#66261399) the signals longer than 52 bits in CAPL may cause some data loss in order to assign the converted value by using `raw64` property.